# Django sub-admin permissions

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I am creating a project in which colleges can post notice for their students.That means colleges are my client.
Right now every college is able to see the data of each other's students in admin panel.
I want that college can  see only their students in admin panel.

I am new in django and don't know how to do it.

Please help.